# Uncaught exception: Object when loading a glTF model using Draco Decoder in a-frame

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, gltf

I'm trying to load a glTF model using [draco decoder](https://github.com/google/draco/tree/master/javascript) in glitch.com following the [a-frame documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/gltf-model.html#scene-properties). You can take a look to the full project and code [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/chaiten-vr). When I run the code locally everything works as expected but when I run the glitch.com app I get an ***uncaught exception: Object 3*** error in the browser console. This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Chaitén VR 3</title>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/camera-listener.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene
            stats
            renderer="antialias: true; colorManagement: true; sortObjects: true; physicallyCorrectLights: true; maxCanvasWidth: 1920; maxCanvasHeight: 1920;"
            gltf-model="dracoDecoderPath: scripts/draco_decoder">

            <a-assets timeout="69000">
                <a-asset-item
                    id="cave"
                    src="https://cdn.glitch.com/b8b66d5a-73ec-4bfe-8bfc-6ac0f5e30e89%2Fcueva_6_dcompress_1.gltf">
                </a-asset-item>
            </a-assets>

            <a-sky
                color="#000">
            </a-sky>

            <a-gltf-model
                src="#cave"
                scale="1 1 1"
                position="0 0 -10"
                rotation="-90 90 0"
                shadow="cast: true"
                sound="src: https://cdn.glitch.com/b8b66d5a-73ec-4bfe-8bfc-6ac0f5e30e89%2Fcave_1.mp3; autoplay: true; loop: true; volume: 2">
            </a-gltf-model>

            <a-entity
                id="camera"
                camera
                look-controls
                wasd-controls="acceleration:150"
                position="-4.5 1.6 -1">
            </a-entity>

        <a-entity
            id="light"
            light="type: point; intensity: 15; distance: 10; decay: 1; shadowCameraVisible: false;"
            position="-4.5 1.6 0.35">
        </a-entity>

            <a-entity camera-listener></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
```

I created the original glTF in Blender 2.82 and used the [glTF Pipeline](https://github.com/CesiumGS/gltf-pipeline) to convert the model to Draco glTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this file: [time_draco_decode.html](https://github.com/google/draco/blob/master/javascript/time_draco_decode.html) and found that:

```
// It is recommended to always pull your Draco JavaScript and WASM decoders
// from this URL. Users will benefit from having the Draco decoder in cache
// as more sites start using the static URL.
let decoderPath = 'https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/';
```

I used that path and now the app works OK.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the "Unexpected token < in JSON" error which was preventing the draco glb's from loading.